# removing duplicates in python and selenium

Tags: python

```
longItem = ["Hey there how are you? \n Whats up \n Hi \n Hey there how are you? Whats up \n Wow"]
```

output should be:

```
longItemNoDuplicates = ["Hey there how are you? Whats up Wow"]
```

if you were to encounter a problem like this how could it be solved? 
I know you're wondering why is it just one element in a list why not break them up?

I have a specific problem that is exactly like this and Im lost and don't know how to solve it

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: What is your expected result? If you split the list simply on the `\n`, everything is still unique because of spaces (first two elements) and different wordings between the last two.

Comment: when you want to drop duplicates in a list (not exactly your use case), use `set`

Comment: Duplicates of what? There's only one element. You mean the words? The letters?

Comment: Why do you have a list containing a single item? Why not a string?

Comment: There is no question mark in the original and that output *is* a duplicate.

Comment: im sorry everyone if Im wasn't very explicit with what I was exactly trying to do I wanted to keep it simple. but turned out to be more complicated if stated that way

Comment: @wahwahwah That's why I did so far. I edited everything to show exactly what I am doing now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need something like this?

```
longItem = ["..."] #your item
longItemStr = "".join(longItem).replace('\n ', '\n') # make a string out of list
shortl = longItemStr.partition('\n') # define the phrase length
longItemStr = longItemStr[:len(shortl[0])] # cut other copies
print(longItemStr)
```

The output is simply:

```
'Hey there how are you'
```

*UPDATE*

yes, this is entirely different task :)
Try this:

```
s = ['''...''' ] #your data
ss = ''.join(s) #make string
ss = ss.split('\n') #split each element to list
print(set(ss)) #print set with unique data
```

*UPDATE 2*

To print all unique elements use:

```
z = [[i] for i in set(ss)] #make a list for each element in set
for i in range(len(z)): #use for-loop to print them out
    u = ''.join(z[i])
    u = u[:-9] #delete last 9 characters ([CHANGE] thing)
    print(u)
```

The output is:

```
'''MIDODRINE HCL 2.5 MG   1 TAB(S) TWICE PER DAY ORAL 
REGULAR INSULIN SLIDING SCALE 150-200 4U 201-250 6U DAILY SUBCUTANEOUS 
FLUTICASONE PROPIONATE 50 MCG/DOSE ML DAILY NASAL 
B COMPLEX 1 TAB(S) DAILY ORAL 
VIT B 12 1000U 1 CAP(S) DAILY ORAL 
MAGNESIUM 250 MG  1 TAB(S) DAILY ORAL 
REGULAR INSULIN SLIDING SCALE 150-200 4U 201-250 6U DAILY SUBCUTANEOUS
FOLIC ACID 800 MCG 1 TAB(S) DAILY ORAL 
VIT B 12 1000U 1 CAP(S) DAILY ORAL
VIT-D3 1000U 1 CAP(S) DAILY ORAL 
LANTUS 100 UNIT/ML 40U TWICE PER DAY SUBCUTANEOUS
LASIX 20 MG  1 TAB(S) DAILY ORAL 
CENTRUM SILVER 1  TAB(S) DAILY ORAL 
OMEPRAZOLE 20 MG  1 CAP(S) TWICE PER DAY ORAL 
LANTUS 100 UNIT/ML 40U TWICE PER DAY SUBCUTANEOUS 
B COMPLEX 1 TAB(S) DAILY ORAL
SENOKOT 8.6 MG  3 TABS TWICE PER DAY ORAL 
TRIANCINILONE ACETONIDE 0.1% AS NEEDED FOR MOUTH SORE TOPICAL'''
```

Comment: I edited my post. More or less this was what I was trying to do. Im sorry if everything was confusing I added what I and the actual outputs now

Comment: I've added update to my answer. Hope this is what you were trying to implement. Notice that set data is not in particular order.

Comment: thanks man now this did it!. now one more follow up question. now that the duplicates are removed how do I make them get typed in into it's own line?

Comment: dang man! how do you learn all of that?! wow  with the first update you made I was able to do it. 

but how and where did you learn python? point me to the right direction 

thank you very much though :D

Comment: I've just started to learn python, and I know a very basics of it. I started with Python for beginners from Udemy.com, now I'm learning Pluralsight's Python fundamentals and Python Beyond the basics. Thank you for kind words, it was fun for me trying to find the answer

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
items = []
for long_item in longItem:
    for item in long_item.split(" \n "):
        if item not in items:
            items.append(item)
print(items)
```

Output:

```
['Hey there how are you', 'Hey there how are you Hey there', 'how are you Hey there how are you']
```

Comment: I interpreted the question as the duplicates in the words of the entire string.

Comment: I have edited my entire question.

Im very sorry I was trying to make things simpler and more general but it made things more confusing